# compiles a c++ file that includes clang/AST libraries in ubuntu16.0.4

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. Today, I installed llvm, clang and libc++ as https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html instructed.

```
$ llvm-config --version
6.0.0svn-r311975
$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.0 (trunk 311975)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/jzhu/build/bin
```

I tried to follow the example http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html by creating files called FindClassDecls.cpp and  CMakeLists.txt The only difference is I used `<>` instead of `""` to include the clang header files.

Then when I tried to compile the .ccp file with

```
clang++ -v -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -I/home/jzhu/llvm/tools/clang/include -I/home/jzhu/llvm/include -I/home/jzhu/build/include -I/home/jzhu/build/tools/clang/include -L/home/jzhu/build/lib FindClassDecls.cpp
```

It gives

```
clang version 6.0.0 (trunk 311975)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/jzhu/build/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/home/jzhu/build/bin/clang-6.0" -cc1 -triple x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -main-file-name FindClassDecls.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /home/jzhu/build/lib/clang/6.0.0 -I /home/jzhu/build/include -I /home/jzhu/build/tools/clang/include -internal-isystem /home/jzhu/build/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /home/jzhu/build/lib/clang/6.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/jzhu/sandbox -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 140 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/FindClassDecls-71cf4e.o -x c++ FindClassDecls.cpp
clang -cc1 version 6.0.0 based upon LLVM 6.0.0svn-r311975 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/jzhu/build/include
 /home/jzhu/build/tools/clang/include
 /home/jzhu/build/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /home/jzhu/build/lib/clang/6.0.0/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../.. -L/home/jzhu/build/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/FindClassDecls-71cf4e.o -lc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

/tmp/main-3a7b68.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `clang::tooling::runToolOnCode(clang::FrontendAction*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Twine const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<clang::PCHContainerOperations>)'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o: In function `clang::ASTFrontendAction::ASTFrontendAction()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5clang17ASTFrontendActionC2Ev[_ZN5clang17ASTFrontendActionC2Ev]+0x1b): undefined reference to `clang::FrontendAction::FrontendAction()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5clang17ASTFrontendActionC2Ev[_ZN5clang17ASTFrontendActionC2Ev]+0x21): undefined reference to `vtable for clang::ASTFrontendAction'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o: In function `clang::ASTConsumer::ASTConsumer()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5clang11ASTConsumerC2Ev[_ZN5clang11ASTConsumerC2Ev]+0x6): undefined reference to `vtable for clang::ASTConsumer'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o: In function `clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<FindNamedClassVisitor>::TraverseCapturedDecl(clang::CapturedDecl*)':
...
more undefined reference errors
...
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::EnableABIBreakingChecks'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV20FindNamedClassAction[_ZTV20FindNamedClassAction]+0x28): undefined reference to `clang::ASTFrontendAction::ExecuteAction()'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV20FindNamedClassAction[_ZTV20FindNamedClassAction]+0x38): undefined reference to `clang::FrontendAction::shouldEraseOutputFiles()'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTI20FindNamedClassAction[_ZTI20FindNamedClassAction]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for clang::ASTFrontendAction'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer[_ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer]+0x28): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleTopLevelDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef)'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer[_ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer]+0x38): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleInterestingDecl(clang::DeclGroupRef)'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer[_ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer]+0x60): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleTopLevelDeclInObjCContainer(clang::DeclGroupRef)'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer[_ZTV22FindNamedClassConsumer]+0x68): undefined reference to `clang::ASTConsumer::HandleImplicitImportDecl(clang::ImportDecl*)'
/tmp/main-3a7b68.o:(.rodata._ZTI22FindNamedClassConsumer[_ZTI22FindNamedClassConsumer]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for clang::ASTConsumer'
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Questions:

- 1. Do I suppose to build the .cpp file with such arguments?
- 2. How to avoid manually enter the path to the header files every time I run the clang++ compiler.
- 3. Have I done something wrong?
- 4. Do I need a -L for which library do I need to link (crt1.o? crti.o?)

> /home/jzhu/build/lib$ ls
>
> Analysis                          libc++.so.1.0
> libLLVMHexagonInfo.a          libLLVMSparcCodeGen.a AsmParser
> libDynamicLibraryLib.a        libLLVMInstCombine.a
> libLLVMSparcDesc.a BinaryFormat                      libgtest.a
> libLLVMInstrumentation.a      libLLVMSparcDisassembler.a Bitcode
> libgtest_main.a               libLLVMInterpreter.a
> libLLVMSparcInfo.a BugpointPasses.so
> libLLVMAArch64AsmParser.a     libLLVMipo.a
> libLLVMSupport.a clang
> libLLVMAArch64AsmPrinter.a    libLLVMIRReader.a
> libLLVMSymbolize.a cmake
> libLLVMAArch64CodeGen.a       libLLVMLanaiAsmParser.a
> libLLVMSystemZAsmParser.a CMakeFiles
> libLLVMAArch64Desc.a          libLLVMLanaiAsmPrinter.a
> libLLVMSystemZAsmPrinter.a cmake_install.cmake
> libLLVMAArch64Disassembler.a  libLLVMLanaiCodeGen.a
> libLLVMSystemZCodeGen.a CodeGen
> libLLVMAArch64Info.a          libLLVMLanaiDesc.a
> libLLVMSystemZDesc.a DebugInfo
> libLLVMAArch64Utils.a         libLLVMLanaiDisassembler.a
> libLLVMSystemZDisassembler.a Demangle
> libLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser.a      libLLVMLanaiInfo.a
> libLLVMSystemZInfo.a ExecutionEngine
> libLLVMAMDGPUAsmPrinter.a     libLLVMLibDriver.a
> libLLVMTableGen.a FuzzMutate
> libLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen.a        libLLVMLineEditor.a
> libLLVMTarget.a IR                                libLLVMAMDGPUDesc.a
> libLLVMLinker.a               libLLVMTestingSupport.a IRReader
> libLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler.a   libLLVMLTO.a
> libLLVMTransformUtils.a libc++.a
> libLLVMAMDGPUInfo.a           libLLVMMC.a
> libLLVMVectorize.a libc++abi.a
> libLLVMAMDGPUUtils.a          libLLVMMCDisassembler.a
> libLLVMWindowsManifest.a libc++abi.so
> libLLVMAnalysis.a             libLLVMMCJIT.a
> libLLVMX86AsmParser.a libc++abi.so.1
> libLLVMARMAsmParser.a         libLLVMMCParser.a
> libLLVMX86AsmPrinter.a libc++abi.so.1.0
> libLLVMARMAsmPrinter.a        libLLVMMipsAsmParser.a
> libLLVMX86CodeGen.a libc++experimental.a
> libLLVMARMCodeGen.a           libLLVMMipsAsmPrinter.a
> libLLVMX86Desc.a libclangAnalysis.a                libLLVMARMDesc.a
> libLLVMMipsCodeGen.a          libLLVMX86Disassembler.a
> libclangARCMigrate.a              libLLVMARMDisassembler.a
> libLLVMMipsDesc.a             libLLVMX86Info.a libclangAST.a
> libLLVMARMInfo.a              libLLVMMipsDisassembler.a
> libLLVMX86Utils.a libclangASTMatchers.a             libLLVMARMUtils.a
> libLLVMMipsInfo.a             libLLVMXCoreAsmPrinter.a libclangBasic.a
> libLLVMAsmParser.a            libLLVMMIRParser.a
> libLLVMXCoreCodeGen.a libclangCodeGen.a
> libLLVMAsmPrinter.a           libLLVMMSP430AsmPrinter.a
> libLLVMXCoreDesc.a libclangDriver.a
> libLLVMBinaryFormat.a         libLLVMMSP430CodeGen.a
> libLLVMXCoreDisassembler.a libclangDynamicASTMatchers.a
> libLLVMBitReader.a            libLLVMMSP430Desc.a
> libLLVMXCoreInfo.a libclangEdit.a
> libLLVMBitWriter.a            libLLVMMSP430Info.a
> libLLVMXRay.a libclangFormat.a                  libLLVMBPFAsmPrinter.a
> libLLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter.a      libLTO.so libclangFrontend.a
> libLLVMBPFCodeGen.a           libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a
> libLTO.so.6 libclangFrontendTool.a            libLLVMBPFDesc.a
> libLLVMNVPTXDesc.a            libLTO.so.6.0.0svn libclangIndex.a
> libLLVMBPFDisassembler.a      libLLVMNVPTXInfo.a            LineEditor
> libclangLex.a                     libLLVMBPFInfo.a
> libLLVMObjCARCOpts.a          Linker libclangParse.a
> libLLVMCodeGen.a              libLLVMObject.a
> LLVMHello.so libclangRewrite.a                 libLLVMCore.a
> libLLVMObjectYAML.a           LTO libclangRewriteFrontend.a
> libLLVMCoroutines.a           libLLVMOption.a               Makefile
> libclangSema.a                    libLLVMCoverage.a
> libLLVMOrcJIT.a               MC libclangSerialization.a
> libLLVMDebugInfoCodeView.a    libLLVMPasses.a               Object
> libclang.so                       libLLVMDebugInfoDWARF.a
> libLLVMPowerPCAsmParser.a     ObjectYAML libclang.so.6
> libLLVMDebugInfoMSF.a         libLLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter.a    Option
> libclang.so.6.0                   libLLVMDebugInfoPDB.a
> libLLVMPowerPCCodeGen.a       Passes libclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers.a
> libLLVMDemangle.a             libLLVMPowerPCDesc.a
> ProfileData libclangStaticAnalyzerCore.a      libLLVMDlltoolDriver.a
> libLLVMPowerPCDisassembler.a  Support libclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend.a
> libLLVMExecutionEngine.a      libLLVMPowerPCInfo.a          TableGen
> libclangTooling.a                 libLLVMFuzzMutate.a
> libLLVMProfileData.a          Target libclangToolingASTDiff.a
> libLLVMGlobalISel.a           libLLVMRuntimeDyld.a          Testing
> libclangToolingCore.a             libLLVMHexagonAsmParser.a
> libLLVMScalarOpts.a           ToolDrivers libclangToolingRefactor.a
> libLLVMHexagonCodeGen.a       libLLVMSelectionDAG.a         Transforms
> libc++.so                         libLLVMHexagonDesc.a
> libLLVMSparcAsmParser.a       WindowsManifest libc++.so.1
> libLLVMHexagonDisassembler.a  libLLVMSparcAsmPrinter.a      XRay

ps: I installed llvm in my home folder e.g. ~/llvm and ~/build for more details please see the arguments that I passed in to help the compiler find those header files above.

Much appreciated for any suggestion that can point me to the right direction.

Comment: The undefined reference is an error in the linking phase, you are missing some -L switch with the path to where your libraries (*.so  or *.a).

Comment: Don't install clang from source. Ubuntu already has a pretty-recent version, and there's a PPA otherwise.

Comment: @o11c I installed clang-3.9 with apt-get but it has the same problem of unable to find those AST header files and I cannot find where are those files.

Comment: @Marco I am not sure about what and where the libraries that you are referencing to...

Comment: @Marco I added `-L/home/jzhu/build/lib` to the command but I got the same error